# Reading encrypted files into pandas

Tags: python, pandas

**Update:**  I have asked a new question that gives a full code example:  [Decrypting a file to a stream and reading the stream into pandas (hdf or stata)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34978703/decrypting-a-file-to-a-stream-and-reading-the-stream-into-pandas-hdf-or-stata)

My basic problem is that I need to keep data encrypted and then read into pandas.  I'm open to a variety of solutions but the encryption needs to be AES256.  As of now, I'm using PyCrypto, but that's not a requirement.

My current solution is:

1. Decrypt into a temporary file (CSV, HDF, etc.)
2. Read the temp file into pandas
3. Delete the temp file

That's far from ideal because there is temporarily an un-encrypted file sitting on the harddrive, and with user error it could be longer than temporary.  Equally bad, the IO is essentially tripled as an un-encrypted file is written out and then read into pandas.

Ideally, encryption would be built into HDF or some other binary format that pandas can read, but it doesn't seem to be as far as I can tell.

(Note:  this is on a linux box, so perhaps there is a shell script solution, although I'd probably prefer to avoid that if it can all be done inside of python.)

Second best, and still a big improvement, would be to de-crypt the file into memory and read directly into pandas without ever creating a new (un-encrypted) file.  So far I haven't been able to do that though.

Here's some pseudo code to hopefully illustrate.

```
# this works, but less safe and IO intensive
decrypt_to_file('encrypted_csv', 'decrypted_csv')    # outputs decrypted file to disk
pd.read_csv('decrypted_csv')

# this is what I want, but don't know how to make it work
# no decrypted file is ever created
pd.read_csv(decrypt_to_memory('encrypted_csv'))
```

So that's what I'm trying to do, but also interested in other alternatives that accomplish the same thing (are efficient and don't create a temp file).

**Update:**  Probably there is not going to be a direct answer to this question -- not too surprising, but I thought I would check. I think the answer will involve something like BytesIO (mentioned by DSM) or mmap (mentioned by Mad Physicist), so I'm exploring those.  Thanks to all who made a sincere attempt to help here.

Comment: What problem are you having with the "Second best" solution?

Comment: If you're using pycrypto, you should be writing the decrypted bytes into a file. Can't you just assign those bytes to a variable and pass it to pandas? I don't understand what the issue is.

Comment: @ArtjomB.  Well, that may be the problem, but I don't know how to do that.  I'll probably delete this problem very soon as there doesn't seem to be any encryption-specific answer and at root the problem may be that I need to direct output to a variable (memory?) rather than a file which I don't know how to do but perhaps could figure out...

Comment: @ArtjomB.  Sorry, should have mentioned that I already did try something similar.  I returned bytes from a CSV instead of writing to file, but `pd.read_csv` complained it was not a file or file like object.  Maybe if I tried same thing but for a binary object it would work?  Sorry, it's probably basic I just can't find any pandas-specific examples that do what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Ah, I see. I have no idea about pandas. I didn't know it expects a filename or file object.

Comment: You can extend file to do the decryption for you when pandas requests a read

Comment: Override read method of https://docs.python.org/3.5/glossary.html#term-file-object

Comment: @MadPhysicist  OK, thanks, I'll try to figure this out...

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file-objects

Comment: I'm not one of the close voters, but it's not "not about programming", but "not about programming *within the [relevant] scope*", or more particularly not having an MCVE.  For example, StringIO and BytesIO are often used for this purpose (in-memory file-like objects), but it's unreasonable to expect people to make up their own test cases.

Comment: @DSM  Fair enough.  The reason I did it like this is because when you ask a programming question and include MCVE, then everyone ignores the question and only looks at the specific code.  I agree a MCVE is usually called for, but in this case thought it better without one.  I'm happy for folks to ignore the question or to give ideas/links like StringIO and BytesIO (that may be helpful, I'll look them up).  But voting to close this just for the lack of an MCVE is not a sufficient reason IMO and lots of good questions have been asked without an MCVE.

Comment: Might look into [tempfile.SpooledTemporaryFile](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.SpooledTemporaryFile). I had one of these returned in my Flask app by a user file upload, and was able to feed its output `request.files['file'].stream._file` object (class `tempfile.SpooledTemporaryFile`) directly to pandas `read_csv`. Sounds like maybe you just need some decryption middleware. This data stays in memory as long as it does not exceed file size config, which you can set in your app.

Answer (score 2):

If you are already using Linux, and you look for a "simple" alternative, which does not involve encrypting\decrypting on the Python level, you could use [native file system encryption with ext4](https://lwn.net/Articles/639427/).

This approach might make your installation complicated, but it has the following advantages:

- Zero risk of leakage via temporary file.
- Fast, since the native encryption is in C (although, PyCrypto is also in C, I am guessing it will be faster at the kernel level).

Disadvantage:

- You need to learn to work with the specific file system commands
- You current linux kernel is two old
- You don't know how to upgrade\can't upgrade your linux kernel.

As for writing the decrypted file to memory you can use `/dev/shm` as your write location, thus sparing the need to do complicated streaming or overriding pandas methods.
In short, `/dev/shm` uses the memory (in some cases your `tmpfs` does that too), and it much faster than your normal hard drive (info [/dev/shm/](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/what-is-devshm-and-its-practical-usage.html)).

I hope this helps you in a way.

Comment: Thanks, probably not the direction I'm going but appreciate the input.